# Users that are not allowed to edit their "About me" - can change it from another community

Tags: support, bug, profile-page, account-suspension

I've noticed that if you have less than 10 reputation, and want to insert an image in your profile "About me" section on a site which requires 10 reputation to embed images, you get this error:

> Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Even when pressing on "Save and copy changes to all public communities" - same error.
However - when you go to a community where you have more than 10 reputation, and then insert an image and click on "Save and copy changed to all other communities" -

You don't get the error above, and now have the image you wanted to upload in your profile.

So, is it a bug? Intended? If it's intended, what is the purpose of blocking this if you can just update from another community?

---

In addition, if you have a temporary suspended account that is not allowed to change their profile description from one community, the user can still change their "About me" from a different community that they are not temporarily suspended on.
This is what you see if you're temporarily suspended and attempt to edit your profile:

[image: 404 page not found]

While it does not let you edit on one specific community, you are still able to edit from another community you're not suspended on, and thus evade the block preventing you from editing your profile.

Comment: I think the restriction is more for posts than profiles

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've added a followup to the whole story

Answer (score 7):

> Intended?

Probably (not).

> If it's intended, what is the purpose of blocking this if you can just update from another community?

It is a corner case (even if you're suspended). And not all corner cases need to be sealed tight to still pass the water-proof test.

That you're able to circumvent this low barrier easily by doing some sane things on another site doesn't pose much of a problem. We trust you on site X for this bit, not likely you will screw that up else where.

It is important to remember why these low-barriers exist. Not to block regular users but to restrict the bots and other low life that only visit sites to leave their garbage, either in text or images. For that group these barriers are enough to make them bored and move on.

Worth keeping in mind that the sites are part of the network but are still single entities that don't need to nor have to have interaction / connection with "the network". If you delete all other sites and only keep Skeptics.se that site would still work. So per site, the restriction is valid. And reputation (except from the association bonus) doesn't carry over between sites so this is still within the design boundaries.

It is fine you're clever enough to work out how you can get your images spread in the about me across the network. Consider it to be a hidden feature that we love.

Comment: Isn't there an easy way to resolve this inconsistency, to allow all users to embed images in their bio regardless of rep? The restriction was only really intended for posts; having them in profiles is much less harmful.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog It is much easier to simply live with this inconsistency. Nobody will die over this.

Comment: Don't think of it as just an inconsistency fix. Think of it as a separate feature request. What would you think of it?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I would down vote it the minute I see it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Spammers would love to be able to put images in their profiles ... as would the trolls who post NSFW images ...

Comment: What about my followup?

Comment: @OUR I've addressed that as well.

Comment: @rene Yes I saw your update- but don't you think it is intended that a user cannot change his profile "about me" when he is suspended? I mean, it must be a mistake! because if you tell users that they cannot edit their profile "About me" because they are suspended, and they can evade that- it must be a problem, no?

Comment: You're making problems out of things that are so minor and if it is abused not much of problem, causes little to no damage and is easily rectified, either locally or network wide. There is really no need to cater for suspended users.